# Solution to Tokenized Sending limitations in Salesforce Marketing Cloud(SFMC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, security, security-token

So our Prospect want to implement Tokenized Sending Features because they don't want to store data in SFMC before sending Email/SMS and want to use REST API to push data into SFMC but again they want to use journey builder activities, new tokens creation and other data filter and segmentation/query features etc but my concern is after looking at below unsupported features on SFMC documentation, How to to resolve these limitation ? is there any solution to this ?

**Unsupported Tokenized Sending Features**
Tokenized Sending does not work with certain Marketing Cloud features. Review this list for additional information.

1. MobilePush, GroupConnect, or Marketing Cloud Connect
2. MobileConnect QueueMO SMS API
3. Other data privacy features, such as field-level data encryption or data obfuscation
4. Journey Builder activities when not storing decision criteria in a clear state or in Marketing Cloud
5. Segmenting, filtering, or querying when not storing criteria in a clear state or in Marketing Cloud
6. Execution of Service Level Agreements (SLAs) specifically for sending due to the inclusion of outside servers within the process
7. New token creation from a clear email address or mobile number. For every use case, create a token.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_unsupported_tokenized_sending_features1.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi @pardeep, I am having similar challenge. Were you able to find any alternate solution for this?

Comment: @PraveenKumarBandi, Unfortunately not. Still waiting for our SE SFMC experts to come forward.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Pradeep and Praveen,

As per my understanding, the statement about JB could be interpreted as below. Let me know if this is wrong.

Practically, Tokenized sending will encrypt Email address or Mobile number or any PII data. But in general, it is still possible to use the JB activities when the decision criteria is based on any unecrypted fields to branch the journeys. In real world scenario, Journey Builder decision criteria will not be used to take decision based on any PII data. usually it will be other unecrypted field like Lead Status,Loyalty points etc.